# A integer isn't upgraded by a thread c#

Tags: c#, static, multithreading

I have declared in C# a static public int then that int is suplyed to a thread in it's constructor the thread's job is very simple to increment it but it doesn't happen
Here I declare the static value:

```
class Global
{
    static public  int hardcap = 100;
    public int speed;
    static public Semaphore myhitpoints = new Semaphore(1, 1);
    static public Semaphore oponenthitpoints = new Semaphore(1, 1);
   static  public int mhp = 100;
    static public int ohp = 100;
    static public int mmana = 0;
    static public int omana = 0;
  public static Charm dragonblade = new   Charm(10, 30, 3, myhitpoints, oponenthitpoints, mhp, ohp, "dragon blade", mmana);
  public  static  Charm dragonshield = new Charm(30, 10, 5, myhitpoints, oponenthitpoints, mhp, ohp, "dragon shield", mmana);
    public static Charm b1charm;
    public static  Charm b2charm;
    public static Opponent enemy;

}

class ManaWell
    {
        int mana_regen;
        int cap = 1000;
        int target;
        public ManaWell(int x, int y)
        {
           mana_regen = x;
            target = y;
        }
        public void Refill()
        {
            while (true)
            {
               // if (this.target + mana_regen <= cap)
                if (target+mana_regen<cap)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    target += mana_regen;
                    MessageBox.Show(target.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }
 ManaWell mw1 = new ManaWell(20,Global.mmana);
        ManaWell mw2 = new ManaWell(20,Global.omana);

        Thread tmw1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mw1.Refill));
        Thread tmw2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mw2.Refill));

        tmw1.Start();
        tmw2.Start();
```

So target works fine but y won't increase.

Comment: Your code doesn't fit your question.

Comment: You haven't shown *any* static variables. Please give a short but *complete* example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: And my impression is that you're totally misusing threads. You don't want to give every object in a game its own thread. Typically you use only a single thread inside the game simulation itself(except for a few select problems like pathing/collision)

Comment: There is *so* much you can do wrong when multithreading. Instruction reordering(memory barriers, memory model, acquire/release semantics, volatile), locking(deadlocks, lock hierarchy, hidden locks like the event loop,...), Performance(thread switching cost, lock contention, 1MB address space reserved for the stack of each thread,...) So much to know, so easy to get wrong. If you really decide to go that route your program will be slow, eat lots of RAM(in a 32bit process you'll get a very low object limit), hard to debug and I'll bet you get in a few non deterministic bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your ManaWell object and pass in a variable, it will only be the variable's value that is assigned to target. So when you add to target, you are doing only that; the passed-in variable will not be affected (as you're seeing.)

If you're really passing in a public static int, then to increase it, just do math on it directly (and you don't even have to pass it in):

```
MyClass.MyStaticInt += aNumber;
```

Comment: You can use `ref` parameters, but since you can't store a `ref` in your class this doesn't help you.

Comment: MyClass.MyStaticInt += aNumber;
 should I put this where I declared the static number or int the thread

Comment: Thansk you I'm going with this although I kinda wanted to have only one class and to instate it to increase various static int.

Answer (score 4):

Integer is passed as value and gets *locally* increased. it will not increase the statical variable which you pass in

[Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

If you want that your external static variable gets updated you could use the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword.

Beside that you should synchronize the access to the variable as you access it from several threads...

if you have "targets" which should be stored and called later you should pass a delegate (which is pointing to the update method) to the constructor. this delegate you can store and call later

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the value of the variable is passed to the constructor. You are only incrementing the variable local to your class.